# Silverlight 3 - How to iterate over a datagrid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datagrid

Thanks in advance,

I am trying to iterate over a datagrid in Silverlight 3.

I need to walk thru all items, or just the selected items and pull some of the column data so I can do an updates in my database.

So in a button click event I have been trying foreach loops but can't find the right combination.

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: What are you using now - the Items or the ItemsSource? Care to share an example of what your current combination is that is an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
            foreach (var Item in gridExcludedPOGSList.SelectedItems)
            {

                ExcludePOGSList pogList = (ExcludePOGSList)Item;
                accountNumber = pogList.AccountNumber.ToString();
                key_Id = pogList.Key_Id.ToString();

            }
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Rich